# Generate additional files with map meta information using QGIS3 Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, qgis-3

I am using QGIS3 Atlas/Layouts to generate thousands of PDFs from a coverage layer. In addition to the PDFs, I want to save meta information (place names, dates, coordinates, custom IDs, etc) alongside each PDF that is generated, for example inside markdown or JSON files.

Is this possible within the QGIS3 GUI?